# Run SQLLDR with nice from subprocess call

Tags: python, subprocess

I tried below

```
subprocess.call([SQLLDR_COMMAND, CONNECTION_STRING +" parfile="+PAR_FILE + " log="+SQLLDR_LOG_FILE],  env=os.environ)
```

This is working perfectly fine, with no issues :)

When I try below -

```
subprocess.call(["nice", "-n", "19", SQLLDR_COMMAND, CONNECTION_STRING +" parfile="+PAR_FILE + " log="+SQLLDR_LOG_FILE],  env=os.environ)
```

It doesn't work it gives below error

> child_exception: '[Errno 2] No such file or directory'

Comment: I solved it myself. The problem is with the os.environ. I had ORACLE_HOME & PATH set through os.environ, somehow python/didn't like this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. The problem is with the os.environ. I had ORACLE_HOME & PATH set through os.environ, somehow python/didn't like this. Thanks –